# OpenLayers programmatically select base layer

Tags: openlayers-2

I have several base layers added to a map in an OpenLayers based application. There is only one that can be displayed at a time, as they are all base layers.

When the user changes the selected base layer, I store the name of the selected layer as a HTML5 local storage item (an improved cookie). When re-opening the application, I want to programmatically set the same base layer be displayed.

It works fine with `layer.visibility = true` if `isBaseLayer` is `false`, but not in the case when `isBaseLayer` is set to `true`.

Is there anything else I could try for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A combination of [map.getLayersByName](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getLayersByName)(name) and [map.setBaseLayer(layer)](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.setBaseLayer) should do this for you.